# MySQL if statement returning incorrect results with aggregate function

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
SELECT
    itemId, userId, source
FROM table
WHERE itemId = 1 AND userId = 1 and source = 1;
```

It returns 20 rows where the itemId is 1, the userId is 1 and the source is 1 (for-instance). In my db there are more rows for this itemId and this userId, which have with different sources. I want to get some stats on this.

Why then does this query return 0 for both the unique and total rows?

```
SELECT ID, 
    IF(source = 1, COUNT(DISTINCT userId), 0) as 'unique', 
    IF(source = 1, COUNT(userId), 0) as 'total'
FROM table
WHERE itemId = 1 AND userId = 1;
GROUP BY itemId;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT ID`,  or `SELECT ItemID, ` ??

Comment: Without some sample data is impossible know what is wrong. But right now you have some weird thing.  If `userId = 1` then `COUNT(DISTINCT userId)` is also 1 and no need to calculate.

Comment: Since you're not grouping by `source`, MySQL is going to just use some value it encounters for `source` for each grouping (`itemId`); in many other RDBMSes and default configurations of recent MySQL releases, such a query is not even allowed. You'll get similar "some value" results for `ID` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Conditional `COUNT()`

```
 SELECT itemId
      , COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN source = 1
                             THEN userId
                        END)  as 'unique'
      , COUNT( CASE WHEN source = 1
                    THEN userId
               END)  as 'total'
FROM yourTable
WHERE itemId = 1 AND userId = 1
GROUP BY itemId
```